# React Router V4, component not found

Tags: reactjs, components, router

I want to use Router V4 on a ReactJS project (https://github.com/LeMueller/musicplayer-by-react/tree/dev). But I get the error: AppUI is not defined. By this demo (https://codepen.io/HeroBBQ/pen/jGEjNL) the methode works well.

What is wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!

```
export default class Root extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        musiclist: MUSIC_LIST,
        currentMusicItem: MUSIC_LIST[0]
    }

    this.PlayerUI=this.PlayerUI.bind(this);
    this.ListUI=this.ListUI.bind(this);
}
PlayerUI = () => (
    <Player
        cuerrentMusicItem={this.state.cuerrentMusicItem}
    />
);

ListUI = () => (
    <MusicList
        cuerrentMusicItem={this.state.cuerrentMusicItem}
        musicList={this.state.musicList}
    />
);

MainUI = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={PlayerUI}/>
        <Route path='/list' component={ListUI}/>
    </Switch>
)

AppUI = () => (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <MainUI />
    </div>
)


render(){
    return(
        <HashRouter>
            <AppUI />
        </HashRouter>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place `AppUI` in the `class`, it will be referenced with `this.AppUI`.  Better to move the functional components out of the class:

```
    const PlayerUI = () => (
        <Player
            cuerrentMusicItem={this.state.cuerrentMusicItem}
        />
    );

    const ListUI = () => (
        <MusicList
            cuerrentMusicItem={this.state.cuerrentMusicItem}
            musicList={this.state.musicList}
        />
    );

    const MainUI = () => (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={PlayerUI}/>
            <Route path='/list' component={ListUI}/>
        </Switch>
    )

    const AppUI = () => (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <MainUI />
        </div>
    )

    export default class Root extends Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={
                musiclist: MUSIC_LIST,
                currentMusicItem: MUSIC_LIST[0]
            }

            this.PlayerUI=PlayerUI.bind(this);
            this.ListUI=ListUI.bind(this);
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <HashRouter>
                    <AppUI />
                </HashRouter>
            )
        }
    }
```

Further, it would probably be better to pass the bound state properties as props to the components that need them.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. But by your code, "this.state" in PlayerUI can not point to the state in Root component.

Comment: Why not? It is bound in the constructor?

Comment: this.PlayerUI=this.PlayerUI.bind(this); error: PlayerUI not defined.

Comment: Ok. Made an edit, but as I mentioned, you should pass props instead

Comment: Thanks, I can write a Router Class by v3. But route children and cloneElement don't work anymore in V4. I found nothing to solve that problem. Maybe you have Experience about it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244010/transform-route-children-and-cloneelement-to-routerv4 Thanks a lot.