# transform "Route children" and "cloneElement" to RouterV4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, react-router-v4

I want to write a Router in React Project. But Route children and cloneElement  work not anymore by Version 4. I haven't found demo or tutor to teach how to pass value in router in Router Version 4.

Have someone idea to solve that?

My project in Github: https://github.com/LeMueller/musicplayer-by-react/tree/dev

Thanks a lot.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from './commen/header.js';
import Player from './page/player.js';
import {MUSIC_LIST} from '../config/musiclist';
import MusicListUI from './page/musiclistui.js';

import {HashRouter, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


class MusicApp extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            musiclist: MUSIC_LIST,
            currentMusicItem: MUSIC_LIST[0]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){


        $('#player').jPlayer({
            ready:function(){
                $(this).jPlayer('setMedia',{
                    mp3:'http://oj4t8z2d5.bkt.clouddn.com/%E9%AD%94%E9%AC%BC%E4%B8%AD%E7%9A%84%E5%A4%A9%E4%BD%BF.mp3'
                }).jPlayer('play');
            },
            supplied:'mp3',
            wmode: 'window'
        });


    }

    componentWillUnMount(){

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.state)}               
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default class Root extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <HashRouter>
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={MusicApp}>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Player }></Route>
                        <Route path="/list" component={MusicListUI}></Route>
                    </Route>
                </div>

            </HashRouter>
        )
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to pass props to a component via a <Route /> component?

Comment: yes, i think so. but in Version 4. there are many things in V 3.

Comment: I have added an answer for passing props. Also, in v4 you don't nest <Routes />. You instead put them inside other components. Here is a good article: https://css-tricks.com/react-router-4/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to pass props to a component via a  component, then you can use **render**, for example:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Player example={ props.example } /> }></Route>
```

Comment: I think that is what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem at all.